# Swift Setting Non-Primitive Members with get/set Notation

Tags: swift, vector, overriding, getter-setter

I have a superclass where a vector is being created as a member variable.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
         var floatingBlockPositions: [CGPoint] = [CGPointMake(130.0, 70.0)]
  }
```

I am overriding it in a subclass like so:

```
class StreetFight: GameScene {
override var floatingBlockPositions: [CGPoint] {
        get {
            return [CGPointMake(400.0, 70.0), CGPointMake(250.0, 95.0)]
        }
        set (newValue) {
            newValue
        }
    }
}
```

I have a class method that mutates it to set another parameter.

```
   temp = 0
   for _ in floatingBlockPositions {
       floatingBlockPositions[temp].y = floatingBlockPositions[temp].y +  positionsForFirstBlock.y + (groundBlockSize.height / 2)
       let aerialBlock = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "aerialBlock")
       aerialBlock.position = floatingBlockPositions[temp]
        temp++
    }
```

After debugging, I see that the setter in the subclass is being called, but it is not being set properly because the equals operator in the function is trying to set only one part of one of the CGPoints in the vector, which the setter is not set up to handle, no pun intended. How can I write the setter in the subclass so it recognizes what part of floatingBlockPositions needs to be set and sets it. If possible, should I overload the method, or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You've changed `floatingBlockPositions` from a stored property to a computed variable (because it has a `get`). Therefore, you cannot store a new value for it. However, you can create a separate private `var` and set that, and then in `get`, if that is set, return that new value.